Spring Problem Detail Response - How to add custom fields?
Stauts Quo & What I want
I'm trying to customize the Error Details response by including the validation errors. I'm running Spring Boot 3.4 and Java 21.
ProblemDetail::setProperty() is supposed to do this according to the documentation:

When Jackson JSON is present on the classpath, any properties set here are rendered as top level key-value pairs in the output JSON. Otherwise, they are rendered as a "properties" sub-map.

I've added all the dependencies, I've doubled checked them in IntelliJ and Maven dependency:list, they are there.

[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.18.1:compile -- module com.fasterxml.jackson.databind
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.18.1:compile -- module com.fasterxml.jackson.core
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.18.1:compile -- module com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation

Problem
My problem is, it doesn't work, it seems to fail to detect Jackson and keeps using properties instead of adding it on the top level. Any ideas what I'm missing?
Code
Maven Dependencies:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
    </dependency>

Generated JSON
Notice the properties, the errors and timestamp should be on the top  level, not below properties, according to the documentation.
{
   "type":"http://localhost:8080/errors/bad-request",
   "title":"Bad request",
   "status":400,
   "detail":null,
   "instance":"/api/sign-up",
   "properties":{
      "timestamp":"2024-12-22T23:07:11.789380900Z",
      "errors":[
         {
            "detail":"Password confirmation is required",
            "pointer":"#/passwordConfirmation"
         },
         {
            "detail":"Password is required",
            "pointer":"#/password"
         },
         {
            "detail":"Email is required",
            "pointer":"#/email"
         },
         {
            "detail":"Organization is required",
            "pointer":"#/organization"
         },
         {
            "detail":"First name is required",
            "pointer":"#/firstName"
         },
         {
            "detail":"Last name is required",
            "pointer":"#/lastName"
         }
      ]
   }
}

Controller Signature:
  @PostMapping( Routes.API_SIGN_UP)
  @Transactional
  public ResponseEntity<?> postSignUp(
      @Validated @RequestBody UserRegistrationTransfer userRegistrationTransfer
  ) {

Exception Handler:
import java.net.URI;
import java.time.Instant;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode;
import org.springframework.http.ProblemDetail;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.validation.ObjectError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;
import java.util.*;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
      MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
      HttpHeaders headers,
      HttpStatusCode status,
      WebRequest request
  ) {
    return ResponseEntity
        .status(status.value())
        .body(handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(ex));
  }

  private ProblemDetail handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    List<Map<String, String>> details = getErrorsDetails(ex);
    ProblemDetail problemDetail = ProblemDetail.forStatus(ex.getStatusCode());
    problemDetail.setType(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/errors/bad-request"));
    problemDetail.setTitle("Bad request");
    problemDetail.setInstance(ex.getBody().getInstance());

    // adding more data using the Map properties of the ProblemDetail
    problemDetail.setProperty("timestamp", Instant.now().toString());
    problemDetail.setProperty("errors", details);

    return problemDetail;
  }

  private List<Map<String, String>> getErrorsDetails(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    return ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().stream()
        .map(this::toErrorMap)
        .toList();
  }

  private Map<String, String> toErrorMap(ObjectError error) {
    Map<String, String> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    result.put("detail", error.getDefaultMessage());

    if (error instanceof FieldError fieldError) {
      result.put("pointer", "#/" + fieldError.getField());
      return result;
    }

    result.put("pointer", "#/");
    return result;
  }
}


Do you have a custom ObjectMapper being configured in your application somewhere? If that is the case it might be that it is overriding the behavior the documentation states. Also just in case SB 3.4 lists Jackson 2.18 you are using 2.18.1 downgrade it just to check.

No, I'm not using a custom ObjectMapper. But to be sure: How would I check this? I've tried 2.18.0 but no difference.

If your codebase doesn't have a Bean defining it, then you probably don't. So I would suggest creating a small reproducible project (and check if the problem also happens) and post it at the Spring board then.

I did this meanwhile and there it works. Could it be that some other dependency in pom.xml is auto wiring another mapper? If yes, how can I figure that out? Guess I'll have to step through and debug the callstack...

You could check the dependency tree to see if anything else is pulling an old version of it. Run mvn dependency:tree and check if there are more than one jackson databind being pulled in.

Also compare it, your project's tree, with the test project tree.

It is unlikely that a dependency is wiring it. Unless is something internal that you are importing in your project. I would be surprised if something external is doing that :D
